# Unable to perform NULL CHECK on DateTime type variable in IF condition and also while performing TERNARY operation

Tags: flutter, dart, null, dart-null-safety

I have watched multiple videos for the solution but could not find the solution . I have declared a variable of `DateTime` type named `_selectedDate`. Firstly the complier is asking me to initialize the variable. With what value show I initialize it ? Also , I am performing a NULL check like this:

```
if(_selectedData == null )
```

As soon as I code this , there is an error which says `The operand cannot be null,so the condition is always false , try removing  the condition .` Also ,  when I am performing a NULL check while using ternary operator , the complier is throwing the same error. I have also tried making this `DateTime` variable as nullable using question mark sign (?) but it doesn't work.

I am using a Date Picker in my app. It opens on a button click named CHOOSE DATE. I am expecting that whatever date I chose from the calendar , should be shown in the area where by default it is written "No Date Chosen ! . Code is given below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addTx;

  const NewTransaction(this.addTx, {super.key});

  @override
  State<NewTransaction> createState() => _NewTransactionState();
}

class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();

  final _amountController = TextEditingController();

  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  void _submitData() {
    if (_amountController.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    final enteredTitle = _titleController.text;
    final enteredOutput = double.parse(_amountController.text);
    widget.addTx(enteredTitle, enteredOutput);

// In the below statement I am not able to perform Null check on _selectedDate (_selectedDate == null).

    if (enteredTitle.isEmpty || enteredOutput <= 0 || _selectedDate == null) {                         
      return;
    }

    widget.addTx(enteredTitle, enteredOutput);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _presentDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            initialDate: DateTime.now(),
            firstDate: DateTime(2019),
            lastDate: DateTime.now())
        .then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        pickedDate = _selectedDate;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
            controller: _titleController,
            onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
            controller: _amountController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
          ),
          // ignore: sized_box_for_whitespace
          Container(
            height: 70,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(_selectedDate  == null // Here also I am facing the same issue
                    ? 'No Date Chosen !'
                    : DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate)),
                const SizedBox(width: 25.0),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: _presentDatePicker,
                  child: const Text('Choose Date'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _submitData,
            child: const Text("Add Transaction"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your `_selectedDate` variable with `DateTime.now();` so it's absolutely normal that the compiler warn you about it can't be null.

You can remove the `DateTime.now();` to fix your issue and also switch the set State like this :  `_selectedDate = pickedDate;`

Then on your `showDatePicker` result, call the `setState` method with `pickedDate` even if it is null like this :

```
showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2019),
        lastDate: DateTime.now())
    .then((pickedDate) {
  // if (pickedDate == null) {
  //  return;
  // }
  setState(() {
    _selectedDate = pickedDate!;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help  F Perroch . changing the setState() as you told really worked out. But I also want a functionality according to which if the user clicks on cancel that is , if the user doesn't select any date then it should show No date Chosen !  and now in my case its still showing the selected date. In the IF condition and while using ternary operator , complier is still saying " The operand can't be null. " I have already tried making the _selectedDate variable "nullable" by using ? . The compiler does not show the error but the desired output is not attained. Thanks for  helping Sir.

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain you how to get a null date ;)

Comment: Sir , I am a beginner in Flutter .  I am not getting you. Will you please elaborate , specially using code . I am not able to understand how to get a null date . Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I've edited again my answer. I hope it will help you

Comment: Sir , its still not working , the compiler says "Except an Identifier". The compiler throws this error  in setState method after _selectedDate before semicolon . Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Sorry, the ctrl+z have cancelled to much :D

Comment: Sir , it is throwing an error stating "A value of type DateTime? can't be assigned to a variable of type DateTime. Try changing the type of variable or casting the right- hand type to 'DateTime'. "  Thanks for the cooperation Sir.

Comment: It's null safety issue, add a ! after pickedDate ;)

Comment: Sir there is no compilation error now . But what I want is that when no date is selected  it should display NO DATE CHOSEN but in my case it shows today's date that is the default selected date. Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to go to bed. I'll try tomorrow! Good night

Comment: Did you removed the affectation ? Replace DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now(); with DateTime _selectedDate;